# Need to delete all tags with 1 count from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row

I have a big tag database which has 100s of thousands of "1 count tag" rows:

[image]

Is there a easy way I can remove all these rows from my datebase?
deleting them one by one would take me a life time :D

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from tags where tag_count = 1;
```

Assuming the column that has the count is called tag_count since I cannot see it.

Comment: Hi ive added a better image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Tags` table that defines the tags, and a `TagSummary` view that shows the number of times each tag is used, you can then do a delete query:

```
DELETE FROM Tags
WHERE TagID IN 
    (SELECT TagID From TagSummary WHERE TagCount=1)
```

Comment: Hi ive added a better image. Thanks